# How can i copy a python dataframe in Excel sheet with conditions in cells colors?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe, xlwings

Please, i need your help.

I want to copy an Excel dataframe in a Excel sheet but only on white cells, i use actuall xl wings.
[pandas dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gz8er.png)
[excel sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ULTNY.png)

I don't want to copy in red cells.

Below my python code :

```
import pandas as pd
import xlwings as xw
#dataframe creation
d = {'col1': [1, 2], 'col2': [3, 4]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df

#Copy in a excel sheet with xl wings

wb=xw.Book()
ws=wb.sheets['Feuil1']
ws.range("A1").options(index=False).value=df
```

Comment: it is not clear whay you want. I believe you want to apply styles to a pandas dataframe based on excel conditions, correct?

Comment: `df.to_excel('filename', sheet_names='Feuil1')` could help

Comment: @Yuca, i edit my question.

Comment: I want to copy a python dataframe to excel but only copy on the white cells.
With xl wings, I can copy a dataframe but I don't know how to add a condition to copy only on the Excel  white cells.

Comment: @PaulBrennan, thank you, but i know how to export a dataframe to Excel, my question is how to copy a pandas dataframe in an excel sheet created by xl wings and copy only on white cells

Comment: only white cells could be constructed as only col1, agree?

Comment: @Yuca, i don't want to copy in red cells, the red cells must be empty.

Comment: I add the pandas dataframe and the excel sheet as i want. I think it's clear now

Answer (score 0):

#### If I understood your question...

You can use the pandas [excel writer](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.ExcelWriter.html) (look also parameters of the  [`to_excel`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html)):

```
writer = pd.ExcelWriter("Output.xlsx", engine='xlsxwriter')

# Convert the dataframe to an XlsxWriter Excel object.
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Feuil1')

# Get the xlsxwriter workbook and worksheet objects.
workbook  = writer.book
worksheet = writer.sheets['Feuil1']

# Add some cell formats
header_format = workbook.add_format({
    'bold': True,
    'text_wrap': True,
    'valign': 'vcenter',
    'align': 'center',
    'bottom': 1}
)

# Create a base format
format1 = workbook.add_format({'align': 'center', 'border': False})

# Create a "red" format
format2 = workbook.add_format({'bg_color': '#FFC7CE',
                               'font_color': '#9C0006'})

# Create a "green" format
format3 = workbook.add_format({'bg_color': '#CDFFC7',
                               'font_color': '#324f2F'})

# Set the column width and format
worksheet.set_column('A:N', 16, format1)
worksheet.conditional_format(
    'A1:N800',
    {'type': 'cell', 'criteria': '==', 'value': '"no data"','format': format2}
)

worksheet.conditional_format(
    'A1:N500',
    {'type': 'cell', 'criteria': '==', 'value': '"not applicable"', 'format': format3}
)

# Write the column headers with the defined format.
for col_num, value in enumerate(df.columns.values):
    worksheet.write(0, col_num, value, header_format)
```

[Here](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/working_with_pandas.html) you can find a big tutorial

Comment: @Rhoman Zhuravlev, thank you but, this doesn't answer my question thank you,  my question is how to copy a pandas dataframe in an excel sheet created by xl wings and copy only on white cells. Please see the excel sheet and dataframe examples.

Answer (score 0):

The picture of your excel sheet shows red cells without any content. That means the following solution should work.
Just copy the dataframe as you already do in your question, and then delete the content of the cells with red background colour. Just add the following lines to your code:

```
for cell in ws.used_range:
    if cell.api.Interior.Color == xw.utils.rgb_to_int((217,217,217)):
        cell.clear_contents()
```

You need to fill in the RGB values of your background colour in `.rgb_to_int((217,217,217))`.